# Bootstrap: Shrink Column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have a table with tree columns. I want the "small" column to be as small as possible.

I thought [col-auto](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#variable-width-content) does that:

> Use col-{breakpoint}-auto classes to size columns based on the natural width of their content.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
 <tr>
  <td>big1</td>
  <td class="col-auto">small</td>
  <td>big2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

How can I shrink the "small" column and give the space to the other columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `col-auto` uses the `flex` rule, but your parent container is not defined as `display: flex`. Side tags `td` should be set to `flex: 1`.

```css
.table.table-bordered tr {
  display: flex;
}

.table.table-bordered tr td:nth-child(1),
.table.table-bordered tr td:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
 <tr>
  <td>big1</td>
  <td class="col-auto">small</td>
  <td>big2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is your general advice: use vanilla css or use bootstrap?

Comment: @guettli, In all my practice, I have never used bootstrap, since for me bootstrap is a useless tool for me. But I will not dissuade you from this framework in any case. It should only be your choice. But my advice is to use your (vanilla) css.

Answer (score 0):

"Sergey Kuznetsov" pointed me to the right direction.

Here is a solution based on bootstrap classes:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
 <tr class="d-flex">
  <td class="flex-grow-1">big1</td>
  <td>small</td>
  <td style="flex: 4">big2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Since Bootstrap only supports `flex-grow-0` and `flex-grow-1` I added an example how to solve this with vanilla CSS (`style="flex: 4"`).